# JAXB for XMLs with similar structure

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We are using JAXb for parsing XMLs without schema...

One of the XMLs we deal with looks like this:

```
<Trade>
    <Something1>
         <!-- stuff here -->
    </Something1>
</Trade>
```

While the other one like this:

```
<Trade>
    <Something2>
         <!-- stuff here -->
    </Something2>
</Trade>
```

We use the same Jaxb context and unmarshaller to parse these into objects, say `Something1` and `Something2` (Both `Something1` and `Something2` implement an interface called `Something`; the result of the unmarshalling is cast to `Something`. Both objects are -of course- known to the context). However, depending on which class is found first by the unmarshaller, both of these XMLs end up being unmarshalled to `Something1` or `Something2` objects.

I also tried adding some XML->XSD generated schema, but that was a dead end, as theres's this clash at `<Trade>` and several other tags. The error I was getting was like:

```
A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of ',Trade'.
```

Is there no way to handle two similarly structured XMLs uniformly with JAXB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the (single) class for `<Trade> ` defined and annotated? - What would be an XML Schema that would cover your alternatives?

Comment: How are Something1 and Something2 classes annotated? `@XMLRootElement(name=<TagName>) class <className> {...}` should help to decide wich one should be used

Comment: The root elements are the same in both cases. There are two different classes, they both have the same root element, the difference between them starts one level lower. The elements are annotated with the @XmlElement annotation.

Comment: Java code please - reduced to the essentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the class for element Trade like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TradeType", propOrder = {
    "something1",
    "something2"
})
public class TradeType {
    @XmlElement(name = "Something1")
    protected Something1Type something1;
    @XmlElement(name = "Something2")
    protected Something2Type something2;
    // getters, setters
}
```

BTW, this is what you get when you compile (xjc) this XML schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="TradeType">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="Something1" type="Something1Type"/>
    <xs:element name="Something2" type="Something2Type"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

You'll just have a single top-level element Trade, and the distinction (after unmarshalling) can be made by comparing `trade.getSomethingX()` with null.

If types Something1Type and Something2Type are identical (not "similar"), you could use the same *class* (not the interface).